# How often do gems appear in Temple Run 2

Tags: temple-run-2

In Temple Run 2, gems appear randomly. How often do they appear? Is there any way to make them more common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that Gems are a random spawn of Power Ups.  You can see I'm interested in the [spawn rate of Power Ups](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/105831/can-power-ups-spawns-be-predicted) myself.

Given that Gems are treated the same as other pick ups, you can increase the chance of spawning them with the "Pickup Spawn" boost in the "Abilities" menu for each character (when the boost is purchased it is permanent and applies to all characters).

> **Pickup Spawn**
>
> Spawn X% more frequently

Where X increases in steps the more coins you spend.

Comment: Aren't gems different from power ups?

Comment: All "pick ups" seem equivalent to me.  Gems may spawn a little less frequently, but they seem tied to the spawning of a "pick up" to me.  It is a hard thing to verify irrefutably, without incite into the code.

Comment: I believe gems count as pick-ups like EBongo says. There is the power-up 'Gem Bonus' that I think will give you two gems for every fill of the coin meter. But you only unlock that power-up at level 9 (was level 10 before the last update).

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I found a way which at least helps me... What I do is take alternate turns, like if I have taken a turn to the right, I will have to take a turn to the left next, though this happens only when you have a option to do so, otherwise follow the trick, but when the dual path comes, remember your last turn and take the opposite turn then... This increases the probability of gems appearing A LOT.

Comment: This may have worked for you, but can you clarify some source as to why it would work for others? It sounds to me as if you have no idea what influences gem's appearence and simply **think** this helps.

Comment: This definitely worked for me. I typically choose left when I have the chance (because it's easier while playing with my right index finger), and I've had runs with over 20,000m with no gems or treasure chests.  I just now played a run using this method and got both 5 gems and 2 treasure chests within 10,000m

Answer (score -2):

To get more gems you must die before hand with half way energy. This works for me.